Опциональность полей Yandex Geocoder
В документации ответа геокодера (https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/response) не указана обязательность полей, можно было бы это как-то уточнить? Конкретно, какие поля могут быть nullable (отсутствовать в ответе)
В ответе на вопрос Обязательность полей ответа Yandex Geocoder это уточнили только для двух полей, хотелось бы для всех
